# Shift Plot Data Along X Axis Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, shift

I cannot get Matlab to plot a a second time series to specific points along the x axis.
My data are two time series.  Time series A is a 5 X 1 and time series B is a 7 X 1.  I need A to plot on xticklabels 1-5.  Then, with 'hold on', I need time series B to be shifted to the right to plot on xticklabels 6:12.  I keep getting the second plot to plot directly over the first plot without the shift occurring.  I've tried among other things -->

`set(gca,'XTick',[6 7 8 9 10 11 12]);`

and it displays x axis numbers shifting but the data does not plot in positions 6:12.  Any help is much appreciated.  I've seen some online answers but can't seem to get it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab, you can plot something using `plot(xArray, yArray);`. If you want to shift the plot along the x axis, you could use `plot(xArray + amountToShift, yArray);`.

As I believe shifting is not what your real problem is, I've added an example where data gets plotted in the way you described:

```
A = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3];
tA = 1:5;
B = [3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 7, 5];
tB = 6:12;

plot(tA, A);
hold on;
plot(tB, B);
```